# Dateformat in FOSCommentBundle

Tags: symfony, date, bundle

I'm using FOSCommentBundle on my Symfony 3 project, everything's fine. But i want to change the date format. My date display like this

> August 11, 2017 15:27

I want:

> 11 August 2017

In config.yml, my parameters are set to french but nothings change.

Comment: Please provide us how you are changing the date. Regards

Comment: @Albeis you can have a look on my answer there is a link that may  helps you .Regards

Comment: thanks but is not for me,it is for @Simon Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the entity that contain the '$createdAT'  in this path :

FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Model/Comment.php

and to change the format you should change it from the twig in this path :

FOSCommentBundle/Resources/views/Thread/comment_content.html.twig

so you change this line to get the format you want  :

```
{{  comment.createdAt|date("d/m/Y", false) }}
```

check this link if u want to know more about date format in twig :

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont think if it good solution:

`{{  comment.createdAt|date("d/m/Y", false) }}`

When you refreshed library in vendor, you will lost your changes. The better way is change it in config like that:

`# Twig Configuration
twig:
    date:
        format: d/m/Y`